# Python, DataFrame Indexing Warning Problem

Tags: python

this is my code.
(df = DataFrame Object)

```
[185] df = input_df.copy()
[186]      df['date_time'] = df['date_time'].dt.date
[187]      df['trade_status'][df['trade_status'] == 'DONE'] = 'FILLED'
```

this is my run window.

```
C:\Practice\Report\src\service\ReportService.py:187: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

How should I change the code `187 line`?
Since the df is a copy from DataFram, do I need to modify `any other code`?
Help me, Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy.where:

```
df['trade_status'] = np.where(df['trade_status']=='DONE', 'FILLED', df['trade_status'])
```

Edit:

Or you can use pandas.where:

```
df['trade_status'] = df['trade_status'].where(df['trade_status']!='DONE', 'FILLED')
```